# Set text alignment in div tag

Tags: html

I have a div tag in which there is an image in left corner and in the middle of the div tag I want to write title of my web application. But I am not able to set text alignment in middle of the div tag. I tried `text-align`,`valign` properties with various values but could not set it. Can you please guide me how to to this.

**CSS for my div tag is as below**

```
    #head
    {
    background-color: #EEE685;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent:10;
    text-align:justify; 
     }
```

Comment: Would you please indent your code?

Comment: can you please give the HTML code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `text-align: center;`, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alp82/e3hgu/

Answer (score 2):

Applying CSS `text-align:center` to a block element centers its contents.

Answer (score -2):

```
<div>
    <img alt="" src="images/accessbg.jpg" align="left"></img>
    <h2 align="center">Test</h2>
</div>
```

The above code will work for you.

Comment: This is a bad practice. Do not use the align attribute, because it is deprecated.